# How to put height 100% at the links of a navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap, and I have the following code to generate an navbar with an avatar in a dropdown:

Check this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/X4drb/embedded/result/**

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30&text=logo" ></a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Hello</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Stack</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Overflow</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img id="avatar" class="img-circle mr1" src="http://placehold.it/30x30&text=photo" > John Doe <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" data-pageindex="3">Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.caret {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#avatar, .navbar-brand {
    margin-right: 5px
}

.navbar-nav {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
}
```

But, as you see, the list of the links with *Hello*, *Stack* and *Overflow* doesn't reach the end of the navbar:

[image]

Do you have any idea to fix it? I tried putting `height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0` to the list items of the links, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try line-height?

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav li a:link {
    line-height: 32px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X4drb/9/

Answer (score 0):

Your ul is not getting proper height. Give the height of ul same as outer div.

Comment: To be honest this is pretty much a fix. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/X4drb/12/) Setting a height (in `px`) will fix the problem.